# Using a For Loop to go through JComboBox names to get selected item

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jcombobox

Below is simplified code which I am trying to achieve aiming to shorten the amount of code I'm writing:

```
JComboBox box1food = new JComboBox();
JComboBox box2food = new JComboBox();
JComboBox box3food = new JComboBox();

//THIS IS WHAT IM TRYING TO DO, BUT DOESNT WORK
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    box[i]food.getSelectedItem();
}

//Rather than having a line of code for each JComboBox I have as such:
box1food.getSelectedItem();
box2food.getSelectedItem();
box3food.getSelectedItem();
etc.....
```

Comment: Use an array instead: `JComboBox[] boxes = { new JComboBox(), new JComboBox(), new JComboBox() };`

Comment: `box[i]food` is not legal Java syntax, you cannot construct variable names dynamically like that.